# Access Violation While looping through array and threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I was playing around with Threading in windows and made up this example, it should add all positions of a 128Mb array. I create x threads to compute the sum, so i divide the array in x peaces and have each thread compute one of those peaces. It all works well until i try to create more than 64 threads. For example if i create 65 threads i get an access violation in my add function. My guess is that it's an array out of bound, i just can't understand why after 64 threads i get this error.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 128 * 1024 * 1024
#define MAX_THREADS_BUFFER 512

DWORD dwSampleData[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
DWORD dwTotal;

DWORD WINAPI DoWork(LPVOID lpParam);
void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction);
VOID InitializedwSampleData();
VOID CreateThreadsAndDoWork(DWORD MaxThreads, DWORD dwPrintIntermediateResults);

typedef struct _THREAD_ARGS{
    DWORD * pdwSampleData;
    DWORD dwOffset;
    DWORD dwSize;
    DWORD dwPrintIntermediateResults;
}THREAD_ARGS, *PTHREAD_ARGS;

DWORD _tmain()
{
    InitializedwSampleData();
    CreateThreadsAndDoWork(1, FALSE);
    CreateThreadsAndDoWork(2, FALSE);
    CreateThreadsAndDoWork(4, FALSE);
    CreateThreadsAndDoWork(8, FALSE);
    CreateThreadsAndDoWork(16, FALSE);
    CreateThreadsAndDoWork(32, FALSE);
    CreateThreadsAndDoWork(64, FALSE);
    CreateThreadsAndDoWork(128, FALSE); // <----------- More than 64 threads

    printf("Press any key to finish");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

VOID InitializedwSampleData(){
    DWORD i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        dwSampleData[i] = 1;
    }
}

VOID CreateThreadsAndDoWork(DWORD MaxThreads, DWORD dwPrintIntermediateResults){
    PTHREAD_ARGS pDataArray[MAX_THREADS_BUFFER];
    DWORD   dwThreadIdArray[MAX_THREADS_BUFFER];
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[MAX_THREADS_BUFFER];
    DWORD BeginTickCount;

    // Reset dwTotal;
    dwTotal = 0;

    // Get Initial Tick Count
    BeginTickCount = GetTickCount();

    // Create MAX_THREADS worker threads.
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < MaxThreads; i++)
    {
        // Allocate memory for thread data.
        pDataArray[i] = (PTHREAD_ARGS)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,
            sizeof(THREAD_ARGS));

        if (pDataArray[i] == NULL)
        {
            // If the array allocation fails, the system is out of memory
            // so there is no point in trying to print an error message.
            // Just terminate execution.
            ExitProcess(2);
        }

        // Generate data for each thread to work with.
        pDataArray[i]->dwOffset = i * (MAX_ARRAY_SIZE / MaxThreads);
        pDataArray[i]->dwSize = MAX_ARRAY_SIZE / MaxThreads;
        pDataArray[i]->pdwSampleData = dwSampleData;
        pDataArray[i]->dwPrintIntermediateResults = dwPrintIntermediateResults;

        // Create the thread to begin execution on its own.
        hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(
            NULL,                   // default security attributes
            0,                      // use default stack size  
            DoWork,                 // thread function name
            pDataArray[i],          // argument to thread function 
            0,                      // use default creation flags 
            &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   // returns the thread identifier 


        // Check the return value for success.
        // If CreateThread fails, terminate execution. 
        // This will automatically clean up threads and memory. 

        if (hThreadArray[i] == NULL)
        {
            ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateThread"));
            ExitProcess(3);
        }
    } // End of main thread creation loop.

    // Wait until all threads have terminated.
    WaitForMultipleObjects(MaxThreads, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close all thread handles and free memory allocations.
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < MaxThreads; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
        if (pDataArray[i] != NULL)
        {
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pDataArray[i]);
            pDataArray[i] = NULL;    // Ensure address is not reused.
        }
    }
    // Print Results
    _tprintf(TEXT("Computation task with %d thread(s): Added to %d in %d mills\n"), MaxThreads, dwTotal, GetTickCount() - BeginTickCount);
}

DWORD WINAPI DoWork(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    DWORD i;
    DWORD sum = 0;

    for (i = ((PTHREAD_ARGS)lpParam)->dwOffset; i < ((PTHREAD_ARGS)lpParam)->dwSize + ((PTHREAD_ARGS)lpParam)->dwOffset; i++){
        sum += ((PTHREAD_ARGS)lpParam)->pdwSampleData[i]; // <------------ ACCESS VIOLATION ERROR
    }

    dwTotal += sum;
    if (((PTHREAD_ARGS)lpParam)->dwPrintIntermediateResults){
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nSUM = %d\n"), sum);
    }

    return 0;
}

void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code.
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    // Display the error message.
    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    // Free error-handling buffer allocations.
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a very well presented question and I cannot understand why you have received so many down votes.

Comment: You also have a data race: multiple threads are simultaneously modifying  `dwTotal` in `DoWork`. The easiest fix would be to make `dwTotal` a `std::atomic<DWORD>`.

Comment: Thank you Casey i will look into that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WaitForMultipleObjects` has a limit on how many threads it can wait on. That limit is `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` which has a value of 64.

What this means is that when you call `WaitForMultipleObjects` passing 128 handles, it returns immediately, with an error, that you just ignore. To be completely clear, `WaitForMultipleObjects` is returning before the threads are complete. You then deallocate the heap memory, with the consequence that the threads, which are still running, fail when attempting to access the now deallocated memory.

The main lesson to learn is always to check the return values of Win32 API functions. Had you checked the value returned by `WaitForMultipleObjects` you would have discovered the problem.

To workaround this, you will need to call `WaitForMultipleObjects` repeatedly in a loop. Wait for the first, `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` threads. Then the next `WaitForMultipleObjects` threads. And so on until there are no more to wait for.

Comment: I can't believe i missed that when i read the documentation. Thank you :)